# My program fails after the flutter visual studio emulator opens

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Asq.jpg)

```
import 'package:naber/naber_main.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Naber',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff075E54),
        accentColor: Color(0xff250366),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: NaberMain(),
    );
  }
}
```

My program fails after the flutter visual studio emulator opens.

Comment: Close your ide and then again build project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color must be in ARGB format.